# Correspondence between delphi version and the file locations

Tags: delphi

I need to reduce the size of my system path variable.  I have had several version of Delphi on this machine that have since been deleted.  Several versions remain, however.  I would like to delete the paths in the system path variable that are no longer needed.  I could guess, based on the sequence, but would feel more confident if I had a list of the version of Delphi, along with the path used.

Does such a list exist?

The reason for "trimming" of the system path variable is that many products (Delphi included) adds the path it needs to the system path, but when you uninstall, it seems that it is not deleted from the system path.  After installing XE6, and bringing up the XE version (which I have to keep for an old project), informs me that it cannot add a path to the system path variable since, to do so, would make it too large.

Comment: No, but it's a pretty logical progression. XE6 is 14.0 (in the Embarcadero\RAD Studio folder), XE5 was 12, etc. down to Delphi 2007 which was in the Code Gear\RAD Studio\5.0 folder). What specific version(s) are you trying to keep working?

Comment: If you're not running anything from the command line, do *any* of the directories need to be on your path?

Comment: @KenWhite: XE6 uses `Studio` folders instead of `RAD Studio` folders now.

Comment: @Remy: Thanks. Hadn't caught that; I never install in Program Files, so I probably changed something during my installation.

Comment: @SysJames: why not just look in `C:\Program Files` (or wherever you install to) to see which folders still have IDEs installed in them?

Comment: You don't need any emba folders in your path. Remove them all.

Comment: @Ken - I will do as you suggest.  I am needing XE, XE5 and XE6.

Comment: You can remove all the paths. It's a big mistake on emba's part that they screw with your path like this. It's not necessary.

Comment: And a generic trick to shorten your path is to SUBST a drive letter for a folder that occurs often, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86) -> Z: (do this with a batch file, on system startup) , then use Z: in all the path folders.

Comment: If you have 8.3 names enabled on your volume, you can also replace with short pathnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some RAD Studio version numbers:

- XE6 = 14 (what happened to 13?)
- XE5 = 12
- XE4 = 11
- XE3 = 10
- XE2 = 9
- XE = 8
- 2010 = 7
- 2009 = 6
- 2007 = 5

The actual paths involved vary between Embarcadero and CodeGear, between Studio, RAD Studio and BDS. But the version number is enough to identify the product version.

Another way to look at things is that if you've uninstalled a bunch of versions then the path will contain references to folders that do not exist. Clearly they can be removed. Editing the path with the built in dialog is painful to say the least. Use a third party tool like Rapid Environment Editor which will highlight the directories in your path that do not exist.

Personally I remove all mention of Embarcadero/CodeGear/Borland from my system path. When I need command line tools for a specific version I use the supplied batch file to set up the necessary environment for that version.

Comment: Ditto on REE.  A most useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem by removing all the entries for Delphi from the global path. I launch each Delphi version using a batch file which create the correct path for the version. I described it in details in a blog article: [Path issue when having installed lot of software](http://francois-piette.blogspot.be/2013/10/path-issue-when-having-installed-lot-of.html)

Comment: Why do you need anything special on the path? Runtime packages is all I can think of.

Comment: Good question for Embarcadero. The installer add a bunch of directories in the path. So I keep it. The solution I designed and explained in my blog article works fine and produce a result similar to having installed Delphi on a clean system.

Comment: I always run with nothing from Emba on the path.